# How to register OData with ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have an ASP.NET 5 application and I would like to use OData v4 with it.

Here is what I have tried:

1.I imported the following nuget packages:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3",
"Microsoft.AspNet.OData": "5.7.0",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

2.Called this in the `Startup.Configure` method

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ConfigOData);
```

3.And finally this is the OData configuration

```
private static void ConfigOData(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    var EDM = builder.GetEdmModel();

    //OData v4.0
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", EDM,
        new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        conventions,
        new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
}
```

Now the OData calls are being processed by the MVC's routing configuration (most probably because I did not register OData with ASP.NET 5 properly).

Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: Are you willing to use RC2?

Comment: If it will get the job done, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how we can configure it with the [ASP.NET Core RC2 OData.](https://github.com/joshcomley/WebApi)

```
namespace ODataSample
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Extensions;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using ODataSample.Models;

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddOData<ISampleService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOData("odata");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you can try it yourself. You will need to have [the .NET Core SDK installed.](https://github.com/dotnet/cli#installers-and-binaries)

```
git clone git@github.com:bigfont/WebApi.git

cd WebApi\vNext\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData
dotnet restore

cd ..\..\samples\ODataSample.BigFont\
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

This is the result at `http://localhost:5000/odata`

[image: Result]

Links

- [The repository in GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/WebApi).
- [The ISampleService in GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/WebApi/blob/master/vNext/samples/ODataSample.BigFont/Models/ISampleService.cs).

Comment: Where is "ISampleService" defined?

Comment: The BigFont sample doesn't seem to be available anymore. Does anyone know where there is a working OData ASP.NET Core sample?

Comment: Impossible to find the file ISampleService.  I have downloaded the repository and i don t find the file.

Comment: Here is a link to `ISampleService` in the GitHub repo @rdhainaut. https://github.com/bigfont/WebApi/blob/master/vNext/samples/ODataSample.BigFont/Models/ISampleService.cs

Comment: It appears that http://localhost:5000/odata/$metadata doesn't work in the samples.