# A model is required for querying. Consider implementing the EnableQueryAttribute.GetModel method never to return a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I'm using AspNetCore 2.0.0, and I'm trying to integrate OData.

I've found a nuget package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.odata) and also this question on Stack Overflow:

- [How to register OData with ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986163/how-to-register-odata-with-asp-net-5)

I've added `services.AddOData();` in `ConfigureServices` and decorated the api with `EnableQuery`.

Once I've compiled the code and tried to access the api, I get this error: `A model is required for querying. Consider implementing the EnableQueryAttribute.GetModel method never to return a null value.`

Also I have to mention that `IApplicationBuilder` does not contain a `definition` of `UseOData` for some reason.

Anyone able to use this?